# New facebook image requirements and third party plugins

Tags: facebook, magento2

We have been trying to get facebook approval for the use of an existing, already approved (with other people using it) third party extension for magento 2 that helps a user design photo albums. We would like to enable our customers to have access to their facebook photos when designing photo albums.
The initial app review was submitted at about the time facebook started making all of it's changes and thus sat idle for three months as they changed some of their internal policies and handled the subsequent backlog. It was even cancelled at one point requiring us to re-submit it.
Most recently, it finally received a review and was rejected because facebook confused the photo behavior with the login behavior.
I'm not trying to re-submit the review request with more details to show that it's a different piece of software performing a different function from the login-with-facebook but now (unlike the first time) I'm getting an error when using one of the test accounts:

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To
be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App
Domains field in your app settings.
```

This error didn't appear when I created the 'experience' video 3 1/2 months ago so presumably it's something new from facebook's end as the settings in the app haven't changed.  I can only guess as to the cause, but the third party app uses an end-point that is not on our domain but is instead one of their domains for their designer hub which actually handles the album design. The plugin is the MediaClip album designer and the end point is on photos.mediacliphub.com
But the facebook app settings won't allow me to add photos.mediacliphub.com to the App Domains saying:

```
App domains must match the domain of the Facebook
Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary
URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct
these domains: photos.mediacliphub.com
```

Of course since we are the only one of their customers sitting in the middle of a review process at the moment, I'm having a hard time convincing mediaclip that it is a problem with the urls/changes-at-facebook. (especially since I am not entirely sure of that myself)

Facebook, meanwhile has closed itself off from the world in regard to any means to contact support with an actual specific question or inquiry. I've tried joining the Facebook Developers group on facebook and posing the question but so far it hasn't received a single reply or comment.

If anyone knows what might be going on or has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated for as of this point, I can't even re-submit the review request if I'm receiving errors in the experience as it will just get rejected.

Comment: I’m confused, is this _your_ app now, or one offered by some 3rd party? Not really clear who’s who and doing what here. // Facebook apps aren’t allowed to run on an arbitrary number of domains at the same time; a “workaround” for that used to be that you add a 2nd domain by specifying it for one of the platforms you are not actually using; but that won’t fly in review, they want to see it on all platforms you configured. You might not have any real option here other than setting the redirect URI to point to your own domain, and pass the access token on from there to the external service.

Comment: Mediaclip has a designer on mediacliphub.com - technically speaking, it's their hub that needs the permission to view the images, but it needs it for our access to the hub. That's why I'm wondering if it's a new facebook restriction (like within the past few weeks)

Comment: i.e. no one at mediaclip and no other mediaclip customers will share that access granted to our users. But the software technically runs on their site.

Comment: The only new thing I can think of would be the enforcing of strict mode for redirect URIs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#strict_mode But if the app basically runs on mediaclip's system, it should probably be using their domain as app domain in the first place.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but they claim they've had other people get reviewed and approved recently without problems. I'm trying to find out just how recent is 'recently' as I didn't try re-doing the video until early this week.